# "ODBC 3.51 Driver" Access Denied for user '*'@'*' (using password:YES) on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, odbc, ms-access-2007

To create an ODBC connection from Access to MySQL, I followed all the steps given in this page
http://www.plaintutorials.com/install-and-create-mysql-odbc-connector-on-windows-7/

I'm using 64 bit Windows 7, 32 bit Access 2007, 32 bit 3.51 ODBC connector and remote MySQL server : 4.13 (cannot update it, cause many people are using it and they are obnoxious and reluctant to change anything)

My remote MySQL server password contains a special character "#".  I think because of this I'm getting this error "[ODBC 3.51 Driver] Access Denied error for user ‘*’@'*’ (using password:YES) ". But however, If I use it on Windows XO, it works, but not on windows 7. If I use 5.2 driver on Windows 7, it works but this this is causing another issue "Server does not support 4 byte encoded UTF8 characters" when I try to synchronize the tables.

Is there any fix to this? Any help is appreciated.